# Dynamically Assign Source column in import schema "expression" in Azure Data Factory using Lookup activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

i am new in azure data factory V2

i have schema file-

> CustomerSchema.csv

Data-in CSV File

```
CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerAddress
```

Actual Data File in CSV Formatoe
FileName-CustomerMaster.CSV, data below

```
101,Aphilps,R-z1 west loan usa
102,Jons s,202-3 sest road  london
103,Ravi,Old Madaras banglore
104,n Har,hi road -203 banglore
105,Jons K,West-23-34 new york usa
```

Target File with Schema
CustomerTraget.CSV

CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerAddress
----Blank no Data

i have pipline where first activity is lookup activity that bring schema from file CustomerSchema.CSV

output of lookup activity is correct, it's fetch 3 Columns name

[image]

Now how i passed output of lookup activity in my copy activity import schema expression

i have try below but not work

@activity('ColumnLookup').output.firstRow in schema expression but it's not working

please help me

Comment: same example i implement using sql server it will work but what about if source and schema comes in csv file  below is SQL code-"type": "SqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "select  @{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0},@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_1},@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_2}  from [dbo].[DimCustomer]"

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized schema or mapping should follow this pattern:

column mapping:

```
{
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "columnMappings": 
    {
        "UserId": "MyUserId",
        "Group": "MyGroup",
        "Name": "MyName"
     }
}
```

schema:

```
[
    { "name": "UserId"},
    { "name": "Name"},
    { "name": "Group"}
]
```

ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping